# Finding the Dual Space

Tags: functional-analysis

We know that if $ 1 \leq p < \infty $ then the dual space of $ L^p(E) $ is $ L^q(E) $ where $ q $ is such that:

$$ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $$

and I have seen this written as $ (L^p(E))^* = L^q(E) $.  But what exactly does the notation "$ (L^p(E))^* = L^q(E) $" mean?

This has always confused me.  From a set perspective, I don't think this notation means equality of sets.  Does it mean that $ (L^p(E))^* $ and $ L^q(E) $ are isomorphic?  Does it mean that $ (L^p(E))^* $ and $ L^q(E) $ are isometric and isomorphic? Or does it mean something else?

Also in general, how does one figure out what the dual space of a normed space is? Thanks!

Comment: The equals sign in $(L^p(E))^* = L^q(E)$ isn't really an equality, but the two spaces are isometrically isomorphic.  The proper notation would be something like $(L^p(E))^* \cong L^q(E)$, but most of the times people just identify $(L^p(E))^*$ with $L^q(E)$ (because, for most intents and purposes, they are the same).

Comment: It means that there is a duality pairing $L^p(E)\times L^q(E)\to\Bbb C$. Specifically this pairing is $(f,g)\mapsto \int_E f\overline g$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second guess is right, by equality we mean they are isometrically isomorphic, in particular by the map $\phi: L^q \to (L^p)^*$ where
$$ \phi(f)(g) = \int_E fg \; \text{d}\mu$$
There's no real general way to find out what the dual space of a normed space is, the $L^p$ spaces are rather special with the nice form of their duals.